# How to properly close a flowable and close response body using rxjava and retrofit

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2

I am attempting to close a stream coming from an http request using Retrofit and rxjava, either because it timedOut, or because I need to change details that went into the request. Both appear to work perfectly, as when I cancel subscription I get the doOnCancel debug message and when doOnNext is completed I get the doOnTerminate message. I also do not receive inputLines from multiple threads. However, my thread count rises every single time either of the above actions happen. It appears that responsebody.close is not releasing their resources and therefore the thread is not dying (I also have gotten error messages along the lines of "OKHTTP leaked. did you close youre responseBody?")

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
 public boolean closeSubscription() {
    flowableAlive = false;
    subscription.cancel();
    return true;
}
public void subscribeToFlowable() {
    streamFlowable.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnTerminate(() -> log.debug("TERMINATED")).doOnCancel(() -> log.debug("FLOWABLE CANCELED"))
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseBody>() {

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                    subscription = s;
                    subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                }


                @Override
                public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {
                    log.debug("onNext called");
                    String inputLine;
                    try (InputStream inputStream = responseBody.byteStream()) {
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        while (flowableAlive && ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                            log.debug("stream receive input line for thread " + name);
                            log.debug(inputLine);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.debug("error occurred");
                        log.debug(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    log.debug("error");
                    flowableAlive = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    log.debug("completed");
                    closeSubscription();
                    flowableAlive = false;
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of subscribe() is Disposable object. You should store it as a filed and call Disposable.dispose() on it later as shown here:

https://proandroiddev.com/disposing-on-android-the-right-way-97bd55cbf970

Tour OkHttp call will be interrupted properly because dispose() interrupts thread on which the call runs and OkHttp checks regularly if Thread was interrupted to stop transfer when that happened - it's called cooperative cancelling/interruption.

Comment: dont believe this solution worked, although it is definitely something else I needed to be careful of. I edited the code so it do something like the following: return a field disposable, and in the cancelSubscriptionMethod, call disposable.dispose, and the thread count is still rising